# how do you easily turn a flash light into a lamp

Tags: light

Is there any way to easily take a flash light and make it spread its light out more like a lamp instead of just a straight beam?

Answer (score 4):

Take a bottle filled with water. Make sure that the bottle is not colored. Now switch off the lights and focus your light source at the neck of the bottle, pointing it to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 3):

A white, plastic shopping bag. Even when this bag is not completely white, it will still work! Basically, this is a combination of all answers mentioned before :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method would be to use a [Convex Mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curved_mirror#Convex_mirrors). A convex mirror reflects the light to all directions. This can be used to illuminate a small room, provided the torch is a strong enough. This is by far the easiest hack you can use. It is very economical, and efficient.
[image: Working of a simple convex mirror. (The red lines are you light beams)]

Comment: Because *everyone* has a convex mirror lying around...  Yes, this works well, but you'll get a harsh light that casts strong shadows, and are unlikely to have the required equipment.

Answer (score 2):

Stand the flashlight with the lens up and put a frosted plastic medicine cup (the kind that comes with cough syrup) on the lens.  The cup will diffuse the light with little loss (less than a paper cone or cup) and no color shift.  The small cups in which single serving preserved fruit are sold will work for larger flashlights.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the flashlight. On some flashlights (e.g. Maglite) you can screw the mirror and lens assembly off, leaving the bare lamp in place. This will spread the light out more.

Answer (score 1):

Pointing the light at any white surface will diffuse the light.  This is easy to do in a room with a white ceiling.
If your light has a pocket clip, you can also clip an index card on it as shown:

[image: light off]

[image: light on]

Unfortunately the card blows easily in wind, so it's not quite as slick as it looks.  A sturdier piece of cardboard from a white box will work better if there is a draft.

Answer (score 0):

I would get a piece of paper and roll it into a cone with a base the size of your lens. Stand the lamp on its base and pointing upwards. Balance the cone on the lens. The paper will diffuse the light around the room.